# Replacing resources and colors app ios

Tags: ios, colors, replace, resources, xib

I have an App (in Android and iOS) that I want to duplicate, changing only the layout (colors, images and some strings). In Android I can do this easily, by using [Ant build scripts](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html)

In iOS I would need to change multiple elements from Xibs and some images on resources.
I just can't find anything similar for iOS, being it native on XCode or not.

Any link to a framework would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a different target, and so I could assing different .strings and images to each target.
I also used [NUI](https://github.com/tombenner/nui) to restyle some Xibs.